# GIT Master recognizing changes to other Branches

Tags: git

Going crazy here. I think I'm missing something.

Created a new branch, checked it out. Made some changes. Run Git Status, file shows as changed. Checked out Master, run Git Status, file shows as changed.

Isn't the master not supposed to recognize that change and even revert the file to how it was in master? Why is this not happening?

Comment: Git will not make changes on a branch until you commit them. Try committing the changes, then switching back to master.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no conflicts when you move between branches, then Git will happily let you move between them if you have not yet committed changes.  From its perspective, no data is lost irrespective of the branch you're on, so it's perfectly content to let you move between them at will.

If you *do* have conflicts, that is when Git will prevent you from switching branches.  Git can't guarantee that information won't be lost, so it asks you to either commit your work locally (and deal with a merge later), or stash it so that you can come back to it.

It sounds like this case is one in which the changes to your file(s) wouldn't cause a conflict with master, so Git is alright with you switching branches.

Comment: That's the thing. I can't even force a conflict. I make a change to file test.php in my feature branch. Then add it to staging. Then I switch back to master. Edit the file, and i see my change is there from a moment ago, make another change. Run git status, it shows as changed and also staged. Then re-add it while still on master. That shouldn't happen.